# Are prepositional verbs transitive verbs?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, transitivity, prepositional-verbs, prepositional-passive

Are prepositional verbs transitive verbs?

I ask that because some prepositional verbs can become passive verbs and the “object of preposition” can become the “subject” of passive prepositional verb.

Answer (score 1):

A verb is transitive if it takes at least a direct object and possibly an indirect object.

A verb must have a direct object before it can have an indirect object.

Direct objects of verbs can appear right after the verb.  There is no preposition you can put between the verb and the object.

> I hit the ball

Indirect objects can be expressed with a prepositional phrase lead by 'to' or 'for, but don't have to.

> I gave the ball to Mike.

> I gave Mike the ball.

The prepositional phrase part of a prepositional verb is therefore not an object because there isn't a "second object".

> I approved of the expenditure.

This would be passively expressed like this:

> The expenditure was approved of by me.

Note that there is a difference between *approved* and *approved of*, so the *of* is needed in the passive voice construction.

Comment: If _approve_ has no object, how can it be passivised? what do you claim is the structure of your last example?

Comment: Why did you say “second object”?  And I was thinking some prepositions aren’t passive or some prepositional phrases after some verbs aren’t passive.

Comment: You say "There is no preposition you can put between the verb and the object", but don't forget the particles which can occur between a verb and its direct object. For example, in "She took down the suitcase", "down" is a preposition located between the verb and its direct object. Likewise "He took off the label", where "off" is a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ both _took down_ and _took off_ are phrasal verbs (proven by the validity of constructions like _took it down_, _took it off_, but not _*took down it_, _*took off it_). So _down_ and _off_ are not prepositions inserted between the verb and object, but part of the verb itself.

Comment: @theonlygusti No: the verb is just "took", not "took down". This is the word that takes the verbal inflections, so we have "She took **down** the suitcase", not *"She took **downed** the suitcase". "Down" is a particle, a preposition, a separate word not part of the verb itself. "Took" is best called a 'prepositional verb'.

Comment: @BillJ because "down" is a particle as you accurately state, that makes "took down" a particle verb, not a prepositional verb (and "down" is not a "preposition ... between the verb and the object", it's a particle)

Comment: @theonlygusti No: Particle is not a part of speech but a more general term for those small words that can come between the verb and its direct object. Particles are mainly prepositions (and a few adverbs) whose role is that of complement of the verb. "Took"  is called a prepositional verb here because it selects the preposition "down".

Comment: @BillJ "took down" is a phrasal not a prepositional verb, according to https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2020/01/29/let-down-and-look-after-the-difference-between-phrasal-verbs-and-prepositional-verbs/ https://english.stackexchange.com/a/545473/163011 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle#In_English https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositions-and-particles https://www.englishgrammar.org/adverb-particles-prepositions/ and any book on syntax from at least the last century

Comment: @theonlygusti Really? How strange then that the **scholarly** text books on syntax that I use as teaching aids say otherwise. The old concept of 'phrasal verb' doesn't work, as I explained in my second comment.

Comment: @BillJ which textbook?

Comment: "I drove to the park in the car" - "The car was driven to the park" - Objects aren't a strict prerequisite to passive voice.  :Something is required but I'm not sure what to call it.  I'm not a CGEL expert but it's probably some wider concept like some sort of complement or predicate.